# How to install the mysql connector for C#?

Tags: installation, wine, mysql, mono, c#

I installed Wine and now I have setup Mono & .NET

When I try to compile the next sentence, I get an error because I don't have the MySQL connector installed on my system.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

> The type or namespace name `MySql' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I don't understand very well why, because I can connect to MySQL using the MonoDeveloped IDE and [I can submit queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCbFO.png) obtaining responses with excellent results!

Searching on Internet, I found out that I need the MySQL connector (for the .NET + Mono platform) to compile this code.

So I downloaded [the connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and read [Installing Connector/NET on Unix with Mono](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-installation-unix.html) from MySQL Reference, but I have no idea *where is the Mono project installation folder*.

How can I install this connector so the code can be compiled without errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After download the `.zip` file I unzipped this.

This have a couple of folders named "V2" and "V4"

Both folders have the `mysql.data.dll` (the file that we need to register) but I used the higher version number (V4):

1. Instal `mono-gac` entering this in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mono-gac
   ```
2. Now register the library:

   ```
   sudo gacutil -i ~/UNZIPPED_FOLDER/V4/mysql.data.dll #Replace it with your path
   ```

And done!

Now when you will compile a file you need to add `-r:mysql.data.dll` to the command line option. Example:

```
gmcs Main.cs -r:mysql.data.dll #if the dll file is in the same path
```

---

*All this steps were reached thanks to [@drch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955881/drch).*